# javascript how to change glyphicon according to value change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, glyphicons

I am trying to do an optimum level feature which, when a value is higher in an optimum range, a arrow-up glyphicon will be displayed and when the value is lower, it changes to arrow-down glyphicon.

```
<div class="card-body" ng-repeat="item in resTemperature" ng-if="$last">
    <p>
        Temperature &emsp;<span class="text" style="font-weight: bold; font-size:150%" ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}} °C </span>                        
        <span class="glyphicon" style="font-size: 200%; float: right;">&#xe013;</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Sample result with hardcoded value:
[image: Sample result with hardcoded value]

Comment: If you are using Angular (since I noticed `ng-repeat`), I'd use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to apply the glyphicon icon you'd like depending on your input value.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it the following way.
Add an additional class to your div indicating if your value is higher/lower/optimal.
Then get rid of your glyphicon span, replacing it with a css pseudo-element.
i.e.,

```
<style>
  .card-body .text::after {
    font-size: 200%;
    float: right;
  }
  .card-body.optimal .text::after {
    content: "O"; /* replacing these with the glyphs you want */
  }
  .card-body.lower .text::after {
    content: "L";
  }
  .card-body.higher .text::after {
    content: "H";
  }
</style>

<div class="card-body optimal" ng-repeat="item in resTemperature" ng-if="$last">
  <p>Temperature &emsp;
    <span class="text" style="font-weight: bold; font-size:150%"  ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}} °C </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean I don't have to use javascript to do the value comparison?

Comment: You'll still need to set the class of the outer div. Either using javascript or something server-side.